# Using dropzone for xampp

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, jquery-file-upload

When I am trying to use Dropzone.js for handling file uploads on Xampp I am getting

> The Server responded with 0 code error.

What I have checked so far:

- File Uploads are allowed in php.ini
- I have set up proper max_filesize and post_max_size values
- Searched in Google to find a solution (nothing found)
- Checked directory permissions.

Please can anybody help me with it? I also tried other file upload things but I am not able to upload a file to my xampp. What am I missing? 
Any help is really appreciated.

UPDATE: Adding code:
Upload form - dont wonder about action, its from Twig / Symfony

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="upload" action="{{ 'upload_path'  }}" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
                <span>
                  Drag & Drop your files here.
                </span>
           </div>
       </form>
```

Dropzone Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/dropzone.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.uploadForm = {
        accept: function(file, done) {
            if (file.type != "image/jpeg" &&
                    file.type != "image/png") {
                done("Falsches Datenformat! Ihre Datei muss als JPG oder PNG hochgeladen werden.");
            } else {
                done();
            }
        },
        success: function(file, response) {
            if (file.previewElement) {
                return file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
            }

            alert(response);
        },
        maxFiles: 10,
        maxFileSize: 100
    }
</script>
```

php.ini settings:

file_uploads=On

post_max_size=500M

upload_max_filesize=100M

upload_tmp_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"

max_file_uploads=10

2nd Update:

Now tested just a plain upload script without Symfony and Dropzone and it's working just fine. Added dropzone and it still works fine.
Just in Combination with Symfony its failing, so I guess it might be a setting in symfony

3rd UPDATE - SOLVED:

Okay I was able to solve the problem by myself. 
I first uploaded files in Chrome and there it was failing for no reason. I was confused. 
Then I tested it in Firefox and Internet Explorer and it works like a charm. 
I was a bit more confused. Then I was thinking "ah maybe its a chrome extension causing the problem", so I disabled my Ad Block extension. And see there? The upload now works even in Chrome. So if anybody has the same problem, check your browser extensions!

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: yes, restarted it and tried it now with an plain php / html upload script S_FILES var is always empty! i guess thats why dropzone is failing too. do you have an idea?

Comment: Added code to the post :)

Comment: I think you should post your own answer as an actual answer and mark it as an accepted answer so people can easily see that this has already been answered (with an accepted answer).

Comment: Symphony might have some issue with AdBlock. DropZone works fine even with ABP enabled. I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should change name to upload[] for multiple file upload.